# React hook useEffect runs continuously forever/infinite loop, making duplicate of data fetching from APi,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

im fetching data from APi and doing filtering from severside, i'm using useInfiniteScroll to fetch only limited amount of data on the first page, and with this im doing pagination too...

```
const [casesList, setCasesList] = useState<CaseModel[]>([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [isFetchingData, setIsFetchingData] = useState<boolean>(true);  
const { inputValue } = React.useContext(MenuContext);
const debouncedValue = useDebounce(inputValue, 10);
```

these are my hook, (casesList) in which im saving all my incoming data from APi, input value is the value that im typing in search box for filtering the data, and debouncedValue is my custom hook, so the inputValue first goes to debouncedValue and then my debouncedValue will get the value of my inputValue,

```
const [pagination, setPagination] = useState<Pagination>({
    continuationToken: "",
    hasMoreResults: true,
});
const [isFetchingMore, setIsFetchingMore] = useInfiniteScroll();
```

these are my pagination and useInfiniteScroll() hooks...

so the actual problem that i'm facing is that,

```
const getDashboardCases = useCallback(
    async (continuationToken: string) => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      let casesPageLimit = CASES_PAGE_LIMIT;
      if (casesList.length === 0) {
        const table = document.querySelector("#cases-items");
        if (table) {
          const caseItemHeight = 80;
          const heightDifference =
            table?.getBoundingClientRect().y > 0
              ? window.innerHeight - table?.getBoundingClientRect().y
              : -1;
          casesPageLimit = Math.max(
            casesPageLimit,
            Math.ceil(heightDifference / caseItemHeight)
          );
        }
      }
      const options: GetCasesListOptions = {
        continuationToken,
        filter: [],
        sort: [],
        pageLimit: casesPageLimit,
        search: [debouncedValue]
      };

      const data: IData = await dashboardService.getCasesList(options);
      setIsFetchingMore(false);
      setIsLoading(false);

      if (data.result) {
        setIsFetchingData(false)
        if (data.continuationToken !== undefined) {
          const newContinuationToken = data.continuationToken;
          setPagination((prevPagination) => ({
            ...prevPagination,
            hasMoreResults: data.hasMoreResults,
            continuationToken: newContinuationToken,
          }));
        } else {
          setPagination((prevPagination) => ({
            ...prevPagination,
            hasMoreResults: false,
          }));
        }
        setCasesList((prevCases) => [...prevCases, ...data.result]);
        dispatch(setAllowedClassifications(data.options));

      }
    },
    [casesList.length, dashboardService, debouncedValue]
  );
```

this code is fetching the data from the APi and for filtering i created an **Object** name *Options*

```
const options: GetCasesListOptions = {
    continuationToken,
    filter: [],
    sort: [],
    pageLimit: casesPageLimit,
    search: [debouncedValue]
};
```

im saving my debouncedValue to the search Array in the **Options object** and then im using **Options** object in APi to filter the data

```
const data: IData = await dashboardService.getCasesList(options);
```

for example if i have 15 objects in APi, i need to get first 10 objects, and then i scroll down my *callback function* executes one more time and get the rest of the data...

```
if (data.result) {
        setIsFetchingData(false)
        if (data.continuationToken !== undefined) {
          const newContinuationToken = data.continuationToken;
          setPagination((prevPagination) => ({
            ...prevPagination,
            hasMoreResults: data.hasMoreResults,
            continuationToken: newContinuationToken,
          }));
        } else {
          setPagination((prevPagination) => ({
            ...prevPagination,
            hasMoreResults: false,
          }));
        }
        setCasesList((prevCases) => [...prevCases, ...data.result]);
        dispatch(setAllowedClassifications(data.options));
      }
```

it's already done there...

now i want that, if i type something in the search box my api should run again to add my search value in the APi and filters the data...

but i'm facing problems doing this...
im calling my **usecallback function** like this...

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetchingMore && pagination.hasMoreResults) {
      getDashboardCases(pagination.continuationToken);
    }
  }, [
    getDashboardCases,
    isFetchingMore,
    pagination.continuationToken,
    pagination.hasMoreResults,
    debouncedValue
  ]);
```

if **isFetchingMore && pagination.hasMoreResults** is true, then it executes the function, but if type something in searchbox it is not running my function again...
i also tried to remove the if condition in the *useEffect* but it started infinite scrolling making duplicates of data, and i get this error...

```
Encountered two children with the same key, `d77c39f2-2dcd-4c4e-b7ee-1fde07b6583f`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates
```

so i need to re-run the function if i type something in search box and not get duplicated data back, and also i want to run the *if condition* that i typed in the useEffect...
please help, Thank you :)